# How to use outside class in Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a class is written using plain typescript not using framewworks.

```
export class RegistryLayers implements MenuTab {
  constructor(readonly rMap: RMap, container: HTMLElement) {
}
```

How to use `RegistryLayers` class in Angular application which are relations to use?
Should I create a custom Angular's service and there are some use cases to use `RegistryLayers`:

```
1. @Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RegistryLayers {
    private RegistryLayers: RegistryLayers = new RegistryLayers(par1, par2);
}

2. @Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RegistryLayers {
    constructor(private registryLayers: RegistryLayers) { // Using factory provider 
    }
}

3. @Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RegistryLayers extends RegistryLayers {
    //I can overwrite functions of RegistryLayers here, not changins library class
}
```

Thank you for assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply import and use it, there's no need to "angularize" it in any way. Notice that that's how we use, for example, RxJS in Angular projects: without participating in the dependency injection game, you can just go `const myStream$: Subject<void> = new Subject()`.

If you have something else in mind, please expand the question.

Comment: So, thank you! Is it okay to use this class directly in Angular's component? Because from component click I need to call functionality from this library class, and what if I want to overwrire some methods?

Comment: `what if I want to overwrite some methods?` - you can write your own `class CustomRegistryLayers extends RegistryLayers`. Still you don't have to make it `Injectable`.

Comment: So, then if I need this class in compont I intantiate it like `public customRegistryLayers = new CustomRegistryLayers();` right?

Comment: And how to know which methods from library class I can overwrite if this class has not interface